# PUM - do you know what is it?

Tags: parallel-processing, ada

The task is: to compare the software Ada, PUM, Win32.

Somebody can tell me what is "PUM"?

I find answer. Thanks all of you.

Comment: If this is homework, I'd suggest asking your instructor this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per [this textbook](http://books.google.com/books?id=g5HxbbU9LSQC&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=PUM%20parallel&source=bl&ots=9qNPu9mC0i&sig=BaBGYhzXAdSk3Lhe5K1CAsAdKEg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jouiT5GjM8iOgweAkeXpCA&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) PUM is, apparently, the Parallel Unification Machine.
As per [this paper](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aC0u7UYL1IpIJ%3amaths.dur.ac.uk/nass/schweitzer.pdf%20&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESiUpwrsx7F5-NlusU_A7QzSA04VMpUf2imZe_tZrun_16zfzZYqZ6lCI4nU1TL_sc1ilQu6KH3RpwzmpXomY3o_7lOT9DaQvcILyBl8treKwiu_ObcTYcN1BJs6oDRnPUnkKOWO&sig=AHIEtbSBZrRtbxpJw478wMnUkm6Joia59A&pli=1), PUM is a Partition of Unity Methods.

Given the task, obviously having to do with parallelism, I would venture to say that clarification is needed as both are dealing with it in some fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Pum can be :

> Stands for "Potentially Unwanted Modification." A PUM is an unwanted
>   change made to your computer's settings. PUMs can be performed by both
>   legitimate applications and malware, though changes made by malware
>   are more likely to cause serious problems. In some cases, you may not
>   know about a PUM until after it has taken place.

From Tech Terms

Or in another case (about software):

> Privileged User Manager ® (PUM) is a Super User Privilege Management
>   software product that allows you to centrally manage, monitor and
>   audit privileged users on UNIX and Linux based systems.

From AppleCrossTech